# What are the benefits from using the Sun as a gravitational lens for beamed interstellar propulsion?

Tags: interstellar-travel, beamed-propulsion, light-sail

What would be gained from placing a powerplant with a photon beam canon and a light sail on opposite sides of the Sun, perfectly alligned, both at >550 AU from the Sun? That'swhere the lens starts, and it goes on along a line.

Comment: I suspect you'd need to move the power plant to keep the beam on the lightsail.

Comment: woow, where i may ask if sun can be used as laser medium (photosphere)

Answer (score 2):

The accuracy of optics is limited, so to get a close perfectly parallel beam of light does require a lens. The larger the distance between the light source and the lens, the better.

The basic concept here is not flawed. Close to parallel light from distant objects gets focused in the focal point of the Sun's gravitational lens. Because optics are **ALWAYS** reversible, the opposite is also true, light beamed out from the focal point, gets close to parallel. (That optics are reversible can not be stressed enough, confusion about optics causes almost as many perpetual motion machines annually as magnets).

[image: lensing]

But there is a problem. Although the beam is now close to parallel, it is now extremely wide. Just think about it for a moment, the cross section has a hole in the middle, with the same size as the Sun. That is a wide beam. If your sail id not actually that big, and it is likely not, only a tiny fraction of the light hits the sail.

But wait, can you not straighten out the beam *and* keep it narrow? [No, you can not](https://what-if.xkcd.com/145/). The [conservation of Etendue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue) prevents that.

Comment: Lensed galaxies rarely describe a full circle. Could the beam be lensed by only a part of the Sun's disk to aim the parallell beam to a smaller area relative to the size of the Sun?

Comment: @LocalFluff That avoids that a part of the beam hits the Sun, but the beam still gets wider. I can try to update my answer when I have figured out exactly how much wider it gets.

Comment: This answer is problematic. The sun is not a proper "lens" despite the unfortunate term "gravitational lensing". Look at the diagram you've included, showing deflection *increasing* with distance from the Sun. The effect is exactly the opposite, it of course *decreases* with distance. While there is deflection, it is not image-forming but only 1-D *concentrating*. See [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1450/12102) for example. Also the figures on page 5 in NASA Scientist [Geoffrey Landis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoffrey_A._Landis)' preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06351

Comment: You would have to concentrate your radiation into a *very very thin-walled conical annulus (the proper term for this escapes me now)* in order to use $1/r$ gravitational potential to collimate. So I would argue that the concept needs some fancy photon-canon-optics to work (the name of which escapes current science) and is at least somewhat flawed.

Comment: However, According to page 4 of Landis' [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06351), conservation of Etendue does still hold, as long as you are treating the optics of the Einstein ring correctly; "*Because of the brightness theorem (also known as the conservation of étendue), amplification and magnification are the same. (This is a consequence of the more general Liouville theorem, which still holds for the general relativistic case‡.)*" Remember that the term "magnification" in this context refers to amplification of solid angle, not *zooming in* on a proper 2D image.